# Editing tables with MSHTML

Tags: mshtml

Is there a way to create/edit a table using MSHTML without resorting to editing the underlying HTML?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to automate this you can manipulate the DOM by adding rows and cells and tables if need to the document.

One the tables and rows are there the user can edit them like any other part of the document.